# Can't access pod on a running Kubernetes Deployment using Port-Forwarding

Tags: kubernetes

I've tried a number of approaches of accessing my Kubernetes pods.

1. I'm able to run this on Docker and am able to access it through http://localhost:1880
2. I created the following deployment file to run on K8s:

   ```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nodered2
      labels:
        app: nodered2
    spec:
      replicas: 2
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: nodered2
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: nodered2
        spec:
          hostNetwork: true
          containers:
          - name: nodered2
            image: localhost:1881/nodered2
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            ports:
            - containerPort: 1881
   ```
3. I'm able to see the deployment

PS C:\01. SolisPLC\01. Software\02. Kubernetes\02. NodeRed K8S>kubectl get deployment

```
NAME       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nodered2   2/2     2            2           31m
```

4. I've read that I need to forward the port as one of the ways to access the pod via my browser, so I've gotten stuck on this error:

> PS C:\01. SolisPLC\01. Software\02. Kubernetes\02. NodeRed K8S>
> kubectl port-forward deployment/nodered2 1881:443 Forwarding from
> 127.0.0.1:1881 -> 443 Forwarding from [::1]:1881 -> 443 Handling connection for 1881 E0715 22:00:47.383640   10056 portforward.go:406]
> an error occurred forwarding 1881 -> 443: error forwarding port 443 to
> pod af7fd02bc1d1374fcfed02adf08f9590dd82cb7230e6db523ff7211cf7dd9b2a,
> uid : exit status 1: 2023/07/16 02:00:47 socat[15579] E connect(11,
> AF=2 127.0.0.1:443, 16): Connection refused E0715 22:00:47.385258
> 10056 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod

5. I've tried different ports, I've tried to add a load balancer (unsuccessfully), etc.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated; it seems that most tutorials stop at this working "as expected".

NOTE: All of this is running on my local machine. I can see the deployment inside of the visual Docker app and it's running in VS Code tabs I have for Docker and K8s.

Answer (score 1):

Below troubleshooting step will help you to resolve your issue:

1.Check which port the pod is listening to by using `kubectl describe pod`.

2.Ensure forwarding  matches the port number the application inside the pod is listening on.

3.You have mentioned that you can access through http://localhost:1880 but you have specified container port 1881, if it was a typo mistake check logs for more errors.

4.Try using pod instead of deployment in kubectl port forwarding :

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> <your-local-port>:<container-port>
```

To get the container port run the below command:

```
kubectl get pod <pod_name> --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}
```

You can find more info in this [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

5.As you are using `hostnetwork:true` try using the service eg: [ingress,](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) you can find more information about it in this [blog](https://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/) authored by ales.